# Check if the registry has numeric value

Tags: batch-file, unicode, registry

I have a registry key of type REG_SZ. I want to identify if the registry has numeric values

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims== " %%x in ('regdmp HKLM\Software\MyRegistry ^|  Find "v1"') do set myValue=%%y
SET "var1="&for /f "delims=0123456789" %%c in ("%myValue%") do set var1=%%c
if defined var1 echo "Not Numeric" else "Numeric"
```

This code works if the V1 has English characters and numbers. It doesn't work if V1 has Unicode character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest some small changes.

1. Use reg instead of regdmp to get the v1 directly
2. Use set to try a calculation against the variable to check if it's numeric
3. Use skip=2 in the for loop to jump past the header lines

Here's a version with these adjustments.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 skip=2" %%x in ('reg query HKLM\Software\MyRegistry /v v1') do set myValue=%%z
set /a var1=myValue*1
if x%var1% equ x%myValue% (
    echo "Numeric"
) else (
    echo "Not Numeric" 
)
```

Comment: Great! Please remember to accept this answer to close out this question.